# Retrieving entire rows while filtering on an aggregate expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Given this data in table `test`,

| ID | val | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 99 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 95 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 32 | 1990-07-25 |
| 2 | 8 | 1991-12-25 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-05-28 |
| 4 | 0 | 2022-05-28 |

I would like to retrieve the record with the most recent date for each ID:

| ID | val | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 8 | 1991-12-25 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-05-28 |
| 4 | 0 | 2022-05-28 |

This query provides the desired result, but is it possible to do this without using a derived table?
In our actual schema, the inner query may be expensive, as `date` is not indexed.

```
select * 
from test, (select id, max(date) as maxdate from test group by id) test2
where test.id = test2.id and test.date = test2.maxdate
```

Comment: @user14063792468 Ah yes, couldn't quite find the right wording to search for it. Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use analytic function

```
WITH
    test AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ID", 111 "VAL", To_Date('2022-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "ID", 99 "VAL", To_Date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1"ID", 95 "VAL", To_Date('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ID", 32 "VAL", To_Date('1990-07-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ID", 8 "VAL", To_Date('1991-12-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "ID", 100 "VAL", To_Date('2022-05-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "ID", 0 "VAL", To_Date('2022-05-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "DT" FROM DUAL 
        )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        Select
            t.ID "ID",
            CASE WHEN t.DT = Max(t.DT) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.ID) THEN t.VAL END "VAL",
            Max(t.DT) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.ID) "DATE"
        From
            test t
    )
WHERE
    VAL Is Not Null
ORDER BY
    ID
```

Where column VAL in Select clause will have value only where the date is Max(DT) for ID, otherwise is null. So you just exclude nulls...